# SSRS Custom function and Null values

Tags: vba, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I am trying to use a custom function to determine the value for an indicator. The issue is the fields passed to the function can be NULL.  I made the type of the parameter nullable, but then it won't let me do any comparisons.  I am not sure why.

The error is "There is an error on line 20 of custom code: [BC30452] Operator '<' is not defined for types 'System.Nullable(Of Single)' and 'System.Nullable(Of Single)'."

```
Public Function GetIndicator(ByVal HistBal As Nullable(of single),ByVal CurBal as NULLABLE(of single)) as integer

Dim iReturn as integer

if NOT HistBal.HasValue  Then
    iReturn =0
else If HistBal< CurBal then 
    If (HistBal-CurBal)/HistBal <-.1 Then
        iReturn= 2 'Green arrow
    Else
        iReturn= 4 'Up yellow
    end if
Else if HistBal=CurBal then
    iReturn=0  'blank
else

    If (HistBal-CurBal)/HistBal <.1 Then
        iReturn= 3 'Dn yellow
    Else
        iReturn= 1 'red arrow
    end if
End if

return iReturn

End Function
```

UPDATE:

Code that returns #ERROR:

```
Public Function GetIndicator(ByVal HistBal As Nullable(of single),ByVal CurBal as NULLABLE(of single)) as integer

Dim iReturn as integer

if Not HistBal.HasValue  or Not CurBal.HasValue Then
    iReturn =0
else
     iReturn= 1 
End if

return iReturn

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Operator '<' is not defined for types 'System.Nullable(Of Single)' and 'System.Nullable(Of Single)'.

It's exactly like the message says: apparently `System.Nullable(Of T)` doesn't define a `<` operator.

You're already checking whether `HistBal.HasValue`. Just check whether `CurBal.HasValue` and implement logic that determines what to return when either or both values a `null`, and then work off `HistBal.Value` and `CurBal.Value` in the branches that are known to have a non-null value for both.

```
If Not HistBal.HasValue Or Not CurBal.HasValue Then
    Return 0 'presumably return 0 when either value is null        
End If

If HistBal.Value < CurBal.Value Then 'work off the Single, not the nullable
    '...
```

Comment: Thanks.  Never used this Nullable parameter stuff before.

Comment: It compiles, but I get #Error back from the function. The function worked before I made it a nullable param.

Comment: Progress! That `#Error` is a different issue, involving different code. I don't know what you did or what input you're giving it. Your code is currently not checking for `CurBal.HasValue`, if that's null then it will throw an exception and return an error.

Comment: I simplified it down to a few lines and still get an error. Posted code above.

Comment: It was a datatype issue.  needed decimal instead of single.  Thanks